# UI for Updating App Settings of a Console Application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, console, application-settings

Firstly I am quite new to the development world and this is my first post, so please excuse my ignorance if this is a question that has been asked before (I have search this site and others though for guidance).

I am working on a project which will be a console application that will query a SQL DB, export the results to a csv file and then upload the file to a SFTP server. This will run nightly as a Windows scheduled task, hence being a console application. I need to make the connection details for the DB and SFTP server to be configurable. My plan was to store these details either as Settings from the Project properties or within the App.config file. I would like to create a separate UI (WinForms or WPF) to allow users to configuring these settings and am looking for guidance on the best approach to take.

Any advice given is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, that question is much too broad for SO. You need to have a specific issue to ask about here.

Comment: How about passing the settings as arguments to the console program when it gets ran?